# Not able to make ggplot plot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am attaching my module for code plot :

```
source("R/helpers.R")

# plot module ----

plot_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(11, plotOutput(NS(id, "plot"))),
    )
  )
}

plot_Server <- function(id, df, date_var, y_var) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # plot the time series plot
      plot <- reactive({time_plot(df, date_var, y_var)})
      output$plot <- renderPlot({plot()})
    }
  )
}



plot_demo <- function() {
  
  df <- data.frame(day = 1:30, arr_delay = 1:30)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    plot_UI(id = "x")
    )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    plot_Server(id = "x", df =  df, date_var = "day", y_var = "arr_delay")
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  
}
```

The time_plot function is

```
library(tidyverse)

time_plot <- function(df, date_var, y_var) {
  
  ggplot(df) +
    aes(
      x = .data[[date_var]],
      y = .data[[y_var]]
    ) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal()
}
```

My main app. R server function is :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  

  df_metric <- reactive({input$metrics})


  plot_Server(id = "metrics", df = otif_ot_if_by_day, date_var = "order_placement_date", y_var = df_metric)
  
  
}
```

My module example is running fine but I am getting the error in app.R because of reactive value for df_metric, how can I make this work?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Parentheses missing, write: `time_plot(df, date_var, y_var())`.

Comment: It is still showing the error. The problem is not in the module. It is running fine. The issue is in the app.R file.

Comment: The point I spotted *is* an error. But maybe there's another one.

Comment: Yes I corrected this error and there was another one at the end :

` plot_Server(id = "metrics", df = otif_ot_if_by_day, date_var = "order_placement_date", y_var = df_metric()) `

Comment: Now it is making the plot, but the plot is not reactive.

Comment: Can you help me making it reactive?